# How to turn-off the wifi power management in Ubuntu 18.04 live

Tags: wireless, 18.04, live-usb, power-management

I'm running the Live version of Ubuntu 18.04 from an external drive and i need it to run continuously.
I've already set it to never lock correctly but the WiFi turns of after some time.

I have tried to change the option "Turn-off WiFi to save power" but when I do that the system goes to airplane mode. If a turn on WiFi the option "Turn-off WiFi to save power" sets itself back to on.

Any solutions to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If you create a Live version of Linux with "persistence" (Unetbootin, MultiSystem, etc...) then you can make changes that will persist even after rebooting. Otherwise, you can fully install Linux to a USB stick or USB drive which is more secure.

Easy Linux Tips Project: [Speed Up your Mint!](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/speed-mint.html)

When WiFi Power Management is on, proceed as follows.

In order to prevent typo's, copy/paste this line into the terminal (it's one line!):

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Press Enter.

Now a text file opens. In that text file, you see the following content:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

Change `3` into `2`.

Save the modified file and close it.

Reboot your computer.